# OpenACC: Why updating an array depends on the location of the update directive

Tags: c++, fortran, openacc

I'm new to openacc. I'm trying to use it to accelerate a particle code. However, I don't understand why when updating an array (`eta` in the program below) on the host, it gives different results depending on the location of '`!$acc update self`'. Here is a code that re-produce this problem:

```
program approximateFun
use funs
use paras_mod

    integer :: Nx
    real(dp) :: dx
    real(dp), dimension(:), allocatable :: x, eta
    real(dp), dimension(5) :: xp, fAtxp

    !$acc declare create(Nx)
    !$acc declare create(x)
    !$acc declare create(eta)
    !$acc declare create(dx)
    !$acc declare create(fAtxp)
    !$acc declare create(xp)

    Nx = 16
    !$acc update device(Nx)

    xp = (/3.9, 4.1, 4.5, 5.0, 5.6/)
    !$acc update device(xp)

    allocate(x(1 : Nx))
    allocate(eta(1 : Nx))
    eta = 0.0d0

    dx = 2 * pi / (Nx - 1)
    !$acc update device(dx)

    do i = 1, Nx
        x(i) = (i - 1.0d0) * dx
    end do
    !$acc update device(x)


    call calc_etaVec(x, Nx, eta)
    !$acc update self(eta)        ! gives the correct results

    !$acc parallel loop present(dx, xp, eta, fAtxp)
    do i = 1, 5
        call calcFunAtx(xp(i), dx, eta, fAtxp(i))
    end do

    !$acc update self (fAtxp)
    !!$acc update self(eta) !---> gives wrong result

    write(6, *) 'eta', eta
    do i = 1, 5
        write(6, *) 'xp, fAtxp', xp(i), fAtxp(i)
    end do

    deallocate(x)
    deallocate(eta)

end program approximateFun
```

The previous program uses the following modules

```
MODULE funs
    use paras_mod
    implicit none
    CONTAINS

    subroutine calc_etaVec(x, nx, eta)
        integer, intent(in) :: nx
        real(dp), dimension(:), intent(in) :: x
        real(dp), dimension(:), intent(out) :: eta

        integer :: i
        !$acc parallel loop present(x, eta)
        do i = 1, nx
            eta(i) = sin(x(i))
        end do
    end subroutine

    subroutine calcFunAtx(xp, dx, eta, fAtx)
        real(dp), intent(in) :: xp, dx
        real(dp), dimension(:), intent(in) :: eta
        real(dp), intent(out) :: fAtx
        integer :: idx

        !$acc routine seq

        idx = 1 + floor(xp / dx)
        fAtx = eta(idx)
    end subroutine calcFunAtx

END MODULE
```

and

```
module paras_mod
    implicit none
    save
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: dp = selected_real_kind(14,300)
    REAL(dp), PARAMETER :: PI=4.0d0*atan(1.0d0)
end module paras_mod
```

When using `!$acc update self(eta)`  directly after `call calc_etaVec(x, Nx, eta)`,  `eta` is updated correctly. But when used after the loop, only the first five elements are correct, while the remaining are zeros. What are the reasons behind that?

thanks

The output when `!$acc update self(eta)` is used directly after `call calc_etaVec(x, Nx, eta)` is

```
   0.000000000000000        0.4067366430758002
   0.7431448254773941        0.9510565162951535        0.9945218953682734 
   0.8660254037844388        0.5877852522924732        0.2079116908177597 
  -0.2079116908177591       -0.5877852522924730       -0.8660254037844384 
  -0.9945218953682732       -0.9510565162951536       -0.7431448254773946 
  -0.4067366430758009       -2.4492935982947064E-016
```

which is correct. However, when used after the loop, the output is

```
    0.000000000000000        0.4067366430758002
    0.7431448254773941        0.9510565162951535        0.9945218953682734
    0.000000000000000         0.000000000000000         0.000000000000000
    0.000000000000000         0.000000000000000         0.000000000000000
    0.000000000000000         0.000000000000000         0.000000000000000
    0.000000000000000         0.000000000000000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one was perplexing till I determined that its a compiler error.  I've filed a problem report, TPR #32673, and sent it to engineering for review.

When setting the environment variable NV_ACC_NOTIFY=2, which shows the data movement, I see that the compiler is only copying 40 bytes, versus the correct 128.  However, if I remove "eta" from the preceding present clause, then it's correct.

```
#ifdef WORKS
    !$acc parallel loop present(dx, fAtxp)
#else
    !$acc parallel loop present(dx, fAtxp, eta)
#endif
    do i = 1, 5
        call calcFunAtx(xp(i), dx, eta, fAtxp(i))
    end do
```

Also, this only occurs when using an allocatable in a declare create directive.  If you switched to using data regions, the issue doesn't occur.  Probably why we didn't see it before (looks like the bugs been there since mid-2020).  Using the declare directive in anything but a module is rare.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Does this mean that using ` declare create ` with allocatable inside modules won't present any problem like the one above? Moreover, what are the consequences of removing `eta` from `present` clause?

Comment: I just tried this with your program by moving the variable declaration and declare directives into the "funs" module.  Seemed to work as well.  While I can't be sure of the full extent of the issue, but it does seem isolated to when the declare is in the main routine.